# Errors of these types : Cannot find name 'XYZ '. and Property 'XYZ' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, graphql-js

Typescript 4.5.5
NodeJS 16

This is my first ever question here. after a whole day i am at my wits end, cannot figure out what's wrong, tried so many things then posted here.

- Property '**video**' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339) in **data.video**
- Property '**title**' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339) in **data.title**
- Property '**desc**' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)  in **data.desc**
  *you get the idea*.

```
export default function Upload() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState<string>('')
  const [description, setDescription] = useState<string>('')
  const [category, setCategory] = useState<string>('')
  const [location, setLocation] = useState<string>('')
  const [thumbnail, setThumbnail] = useState<File>()
  const [uploadData, setUploadData] = useState({})
  const [video, setVideo] = useState<File>()

  const thumbnailRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

  const { mutate: createAsset, data: asset, uploadProgress } = useCreateAsset()



  const goBack = () => {
    window.history.back()
  }

  // When a user clicks on the upload button
  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    // Calling the upload video function
    await uploadVideo()
    // Calling the upload thumbnail function and getting the CID
    const thumbnailCID = await uploadThumbnail()
    // Creating a object to store the metadata
    let data = {
      video: asset?.id,
      title,
      description,
      location,
      category,
      thumbnail: thumbnailCID,
      UploadedDate: Date.now(),
    }
    // Calling the saveVideo function and passing the metadata object
    console.log(data)
    await saveVideo(data)
  }

  // Function to upload the video to IPFS
  const uploadThumbnail = async () => {
    // Passing the file to the saveToIPFS function and getting the CID
    const cid = await saveToIPFS(thumbnail)
    // Returning the CID
    return cid
  }

  // Function to upload the video to Livepeer
  const uploadVideo = async () => {
    // Calling the createAsset function from the useCreateAsset hook to upload the video
    createAsset({
      name: title,
      file: video,
    })
  }

  // Function to save the video to the Contract
  const saveVideo = async (data = uploadData) => {
    // Get the contract from the getContract function
    let contract = await getContract()
    // Upload the video to the contract

    await contract.uploadVideo(
      data.video,
      data.title,
      data.description,
      data.location,
      data.category,
      data.thumbnail,
      false,
      data.UploadedDate    )
  }
```

This is the schema.ts of graphprotocol. it was automatically generated but its getting errors when npm run build

```
// THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.

import {
  TypedMap,
  Entity,
  Value,
  ValueKind,
  store,
  Bytes,
  BigInt,
  BigDecimal
} from "@graphprotocol/graph-ts";

export class Video extends Entity {
  constructor(id: string) {
    super();
    this.set("id", Value.fromString(id));
  }

  save(): void {
    let id = this.get("id");
    assert(id != null, "Cannot save Video entity without an ID");
    if (id) {
      **assert**(
        id.kind == ValueKind.STRING,
        `Entities of type Video must have an ID of type String but the id '${id.displayData()}' is of type ${id.displayKind()}`
      );
      store.set("Video", id.toString(), this);
    }
  }

  static load(id: string): Video | null {
    return **changetype**<Video | null>(store.get("Video", id));
```

```
Type error: Cannot find name 'assert'.

  20 |   save(): void {
  21 |     let id = this.get("id");
> 22 |     assert(id != null, "Cannot save Video entity without an ID");
     |     ^
  23 |     if (id) {
  24 |       assert(
  25 |         id.kind == ValueKind.STRING,
```

```
Type error: Cannot find name 'changetype'.

  32 | 
  33 |   static load(id: string): Video | null {
> 34 |     return changetype<Video | null>(store.get("Video", id));
     |            ^
  35 |   }
  36 | 
  37 |   get id(): string {
```

This is my tsconfig.ts file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types" : [
      "core-js","node"
    ],

   
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "baseUrl": ".", 
  "paths": {
    "@components/*" : ["./components/*"],
    "@pages/*" : ["./pages/*"],
    "@styles/*" : ["./styles/*"],
    "@utils/*" : ["./utils/*"],
    "@public/*" : ["./public/*"],
    "@assets/*" : ["./assets/*"],
    "@types/*" : ["./types/*"],
    "@clients/*" : ["./clients/*"],
    "@constants/*" : ["./constants/*"],
    "@layouts/*" : ["./layouts/*"],
    "@queries/*" : ["./queries/*"],
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "components", 
   "./*", 
   "@components/*",
   "@pages/**/*",
   "@src/**/*",
   "next.config.js", 
   "public"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser",
    
  ]
  
}
```

Packages.json

```json
{
  "name": "Decentralized-YouTube",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.6.9",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@livepeer/react": "^0.4.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^1.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.0.0",
    "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit": "^0.6.0",
    "@typechain/ethers-v5": "^10.1.0",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^6.1.2",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.0",
    "avvvatars-react": "^0.4.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "ethers": "^5.7.1",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.8",
    "ipfs-http-client": "^58.0.0",
    "livepeer": "^0.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "12.3.0",
    "plyr-react": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.1",
    "ts-node": ">=8.0.0",
    "typechain": "^8.1.0",
    "wagmi": "^0.6.6",
    "web3.storage": "^4.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.0",
    "@types/react": "18.0.20",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.11",
    "eslint": "8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.11.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    
  }
}
```

Tried upgrading, downgrading packages , declare `var assert:any` and `var changetype:any` but then it says on changetypes's turn :

> Type error: Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.

first on ubuntu then on windows but in vain
tried different suggestions from stackoverflow of adding lines to eslintrc and `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: I don't believe you can use `**video**` as a javascript identifier because of the asterisk characters. When the Javascript engine is trying to parse that it could end up very confused including the kinds of errors you're seeing. Maybe I misunderstood how those asterisks are meant to work (e.g. it's annotation for a pre-processor or something). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#variables

Comment: Also, note that Node 14 is [a few weeks away from dead](https://nodejs.dev/en/about/releases/) so you want to be on at least Node 16 by now, but ideally on the currenty active LTS, which is v18

Comment: i added the asterisks when i was posting to bolden it.

Comment: I used 14 , current LTS, 16 but everytime this happened

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty sure that assert is not typescript native function.
you can try to use

```
import assert from "assert";
```

I hope I have helped in something.